# How to avoid multiples events when do mouse over on a element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

The problem is as follow:

I have a main svg with sectors (Complejo A, Complejo b, Nave 1, etc).

http://www.calimastudio.es/clientes/mercatenerife/planos/test.php

When click on a sector (i.example Complejo B), then, other svg is open, and you can do mouse over on a local (numbereds B01, B02, etc).

The problem:
You click on complejo B once, there is one Alert for Mouse Enter, one for Mouse Leave when do a hover on a local.

When you click again on complejo B (or close it and reopen), you can see two alerts for Mouse Enter, and Two for Mouse Leave.

Third click on complejo B, you can see trhee alerts, etc...
Fourth click on complejo B, four alerts, etc

I need only one event always.

How can I avoid this?

I was looking a lot. This is the minimal example that I can show.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-inner">
      <div id="p2">
        <div class="close">x</div>
        <object id="complejo_b" class="sector" data="svg/complejo_b.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="p1" class="container">
    <div class="container-inner">
      <object id="desktop" class="desktop" data="svg/mercatenerife-desktop.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>

      <!-- <img class="mobile"  src="mercatenerife-mobile.svg"> -->
    </div>

    <script>
      // Desktop
      var object;

      if (isMobileDevice()){
        object=document.getElementById("mobile");
      }
      else {
        object=document.getElementById("desktop");
      }

      var mySVG = object;
      var toggleOpacity=true;
      var transparent='0.6';

      var counter=0;

      var type='mayoristas';
      var id;

      var setLocalTypeFlag=false;

      mySVG.addEventListener("load",function(event) {
        var svgDoc;
         event.preventDefault;
         event.stopPropagation;

          svgDoc = mySVG.contentDocument;

           $('#naves g', svgDoc).click(function(event){
             id=$(this).attr('id');
             showLocal(id);

             showSector(id);
           });
      }, false);
</script>

<script>
    function showLocal(id) {
      var a;
      a=document.getElementById(id);
      var svgDoc = (a.contentDocument); //get the inner DOM of alpha.svg
      var color_original;
      var fondo_original;

      $('#locales g rect', svgDoc).on('mouseenter', function(){
        alert ('Enter');
      });

      $('#locales g rect', svgDoc).on('mouseleave', function(){
        alert ('Leave');
      })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) and don't bind your event again and again in function, if it is needed then use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like,

```
$('#locales g rect', svgDoc).one('mouseenter', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert ('Enter');
}).one('mouseleave', function(e){ // use chaining for binding mouse leave on same element
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert ('Leave');
});
```

Comment: It works ok, finally use on, and move the function out and put under addEventListener.

I need to do showLocal('complejo_b'); istead of showLocal(id);

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a category, you run the function `showLocal`. This function attaches two event listeners:

```
$('#locales g rect', svgDoc).on('mouseenter', function(){
  // ...
});

$('#locales g rect', svgDoc).on('mouseleave', function(){
  // ...
})
```

This means that every time you click on a category, you attach a new listener to each event. As such, you'll have two listeners bound after the second click, three listeners after the third click, so on and so forth.

To fix this, simply move these listeners so that they are only attached once.

Comment: Works also. Only that I have to call the sector explicitally instead of with an id:showLocal('complejo_b'); istead of showLocal(id);
Because there are only few locals it is a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

I have done some changes for your method, please try it.

```
function showLocal(id) {
  var a;
  a=document.getElementById(id);
  var svgDoc = (a.contentDocument); //get the inner DOM of alpha.svg
  var color_original;
  var fondo_original;
  $('#locales g rect', svgDoc).off('mouseenter');
  $('#locales g rect', svgDoc).on('mouseenter', function(){
    alert ('Enter');
  });
  $('#locales g rect', svgDoc).off('mouseleave');
  $('#locales g rect', svgDoc).on('mouseleave', function(){
    alert ('Leave');
  })
}
```

Comment: It works, and I don't need to call explicitally the sector and not need to move out.

The function gets the id that I need because is inside the function.

Comment: I added only following lines for avoiding multiple events, $('#locales g rect', svgDoc).off('mouseenter'); $('#locales g rect', svgDoc).off('mouseleave'); Is that not working?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. I was saying that your solution let me do less changes, because the call to showLocal function follow under the same place. That way I can get the id from the click event.

Perfect!